# Virtual Functions and Generic Programming

Tags: c++, templates, vtable

Suppose I have a template class as such:

```
template <class T>
class Foo
{
public:

    explicit Foo(const T& value)
        : m_Value(value)
    {
    }

    bool Bar(const T& value)
    {
        return m_Value == value;
    }

private:

    T m_Value;
};
```

And let's say I have some other user type such as:

```
class A
{
};
```

Then this code is perfectly valid, even though class **A** does not define the equality operator:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    A a;
    Foo<A> foo(a);

    return 0;
}
```

But if I make **Foo::Bar()** virtual:

```
    virtual bool Bar(const T& value)
    {
        return m_Value == value;
    }
```

The code no longer compiles:

*error C2676: binary '==': 'A' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator*

I fully understand why this is a problem. Correct me if I'm wrong, but my understanding is that because the function is virtual, the compiler must compile the function (even if it is never called) so that it can reference it in the v-table of **Foo**.

I'm wondering if there is a way around this problem. I want to have a template class that deals with generic types that may only implement partial interfaces. As long as the missing bits are not used, the code should compile fine. This is similar to how a lot of STD containers work already, but they don't use virtual functions.

How do I do this? Is there an elegant solution to this?

Comment: If a function is virtual, it must be defined and compiled. This is fundamental.

Comment: Non-virtual member functions of class templates are themselves function templates and are only instantiated when first used. By contrast, virtual member functions are always instantiated as part of the class template specialization instantiation.

Comment: When a class template is instantiated only the *declarations* of its member functions are compiled, not their bodies. And virtual non-pure member functions are always odr-used and thus fully compiled as part of a class template instantiation.

Comment: So basically the verdict is that there is no way to get around this. One of you should answer the question so I can give credit where it's due. :)

Comment: I don't understand your problem. As you have already pointed out, just by not making `Bar` virtual the restriction on `A` is only there when you actually want to call it.

Comment: @Corristo The problem is that I *want* `Bar` to also be virtual. Specifically, my actual problem is that `Foo` is an implementation of an interface `IFoo`, where `Bar` is a pure virtual. `Foo<T>` implements `IFoo`, but if `Bar` is virtual, then I run into this issue.

Comment: Well, if `Foo<T>` is to implement `IFoo`, then it makes no sense to specialize it with a type for which `Bar` cannot be instantiated, since such a specialization would not in fact satisfy the contract defined by `IFoo`.

Comment: Actually, come to think of it - how exactly is `IFoo` defined? How does it manage to have a virtual method taking a parameter of type `T`? Is it itself a template parameterized on `T`?

Comment: @Zeenobit Ah, I see. Then this seems to be more of a design problem: If there are useful classes that only partially implement your abstract interface, then the abstact interface is too large and could be split into several smaller interfaces. If that is not possible (e.g. if the abstract interface is provided by a third party library), you could implement a tag-dispatched based approach to supply default implementations in your template class that for example just throw an exception if the wrapped class does not implement the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by Kerrek SB above, virtual functions are always instanciated when the template is instanciated. So there is no way to have your program compile just fine when the virtual method is not used **and** have it fail to compile in case it is used and the class you want to wrap does not supply its own `operator==`.

But you can, however, make the program crash at runtime (with `assert`/`terminate`) or throw an exception.

**Disclaimer**: I don't think it is a good idea to do what you are trying to do, as it allows to create classes that don't support the interface they claim to provide. Use the following at your own risk.

The way to go here is to use custom type traits for every method you want to supply even though the wrapped class does not implement it itself. In your case above this is only `operator==`, and the corresponding code looks something like this:

```
namespace traits {
template <typename T>
using operator_eq_t = decltype(std::declval<T>() == std::declval<T>());

template <typename, typename = void>
struct has_operator_eq : std::false_type {};

// check that operator== is defined and returns the correct type `bool`.
template <typename T>
struct has_operator_eq<T, std::void_t<operator_eq_t<T>>> 
    : std::is_same<operator_eq_t<T>, bool> {}; 
} // namespace traits
```

If you don't have access to c++1z yet you can make your own version of `std::void_t`, everything else is valid C++14:

```
template <typename...>
using void_t = void
```

With that in place you can create your wrapper class template with tag dispatch:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo : public IFoo<T> {
public:
    explicit Foo(T const& value)
        : m_Value(value) {
    }

    bool Bar(T const& value) override {
        return BarImpl(value, traits::has_operator_eq<T>{});
    }

private:
    T m_Value;

    bool BarImpl(T const& value, std::false_type) {
        // some sensible default, in this case you might
        // consider just to return false
        assert(!"Called `Bar` on class that does not implement `operator==`.");
        throw std::logic_error("Called `Bar` on class that does not implement `operator==`.");
    }

    bool BarImpl(T const& value, std::true_type) {
        return value == m_Value;
    }
};
```

A working example can be found [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf79661ff038246d).

Comment: This is very interesting. But I think changing the class design is a more elegant solution as we discussed in comments. Regardless, this would come in handy in future.